# Enforce container CPU and memory resource requests & limits

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

Is there a way to prevent a Pod from deploying onto Kubernetes if it does not have memory resource requests & limits set?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can apply [Limit Ranges](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/). See e.g. [Configure Minimum and Maximum CPU Constraints for a Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-constraint-namespace/) for an example for CPU resources, but it can be applied for e.g. memory and storage as well.

Comment: nice hint although i like policies more :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you could enable the [Policy addon for AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/policy-for-kubernetes#install-azure-policy-add-on-for-aks):

```
az aks enable-addons --addons azure-policy --name MyAKSCluster --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

This installs a managed Gatekeeper instance to your cluster. With this enabled you can apply Azure build-in policies or apply your own Gatekeeper policies to the AKS cluster. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/built-in-policies#kubernetes) is a list of built-in polices from Azure specially for Kubernetes.

[Here](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Policy/PolicyDetailBlade/definitionId/%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Authorization%2FpolicyDefinitions%2Fe345eecc-fa47-480f-9e88-67dcc122b164) is the built-in policy to enforce limits. Here you will find a sample [ConstraintTemplate](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/library/general/containerlimits/template.yaml) for your use case described above. As those templates are CRDs your need to activate those with a [Constraint](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/library/general/containerlimits/samples/container-must-have-limits/constraint.yaml). You may need to tweak them to also enforce memory & cpu requests.

Another Policy tool is [Kyverno](https://kyverno.io/docs/installation/). The downside is that it is not Azure manage so you have to to update it yourself and you have no built-in polices from Microsoft. Here are some examples policies:

1. [Require Limits and Requests](https://kyverno.io/policies/best-practices/require_pod_requests_limits/require_pod_requests_limits/)
2. [Memory Requests Equal Limits](https://kyverno.io/policies/other/memory-requests-equal-limits/memory-requests-equal-limits/)

Hope that helped in addition to the LimitRange hint from Jonas :)